# Why I save timestamps in database, it becomes string when I retrieve it? (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I having difficulty, in determining the reason why *timestamp* becomes string when I retrieve it. When I dump it, its a clear timestamp type. Someone help me what causes and possible solution for this.

Here's how I saved it.

```
$user->start_at = Carbon::parse(now()->addDay());
```

And how I use it after it was saved from db.

```
$user->start_at->lte(now())
```

But it returns an error (it says it *string* even its timestamp)

> Error: Call to a member function lte() on string in file

---

Screenshot before it was saved.
[image]

I tried adding `public $timestamps = true;` in the model, but still not working.

Comment: `now()` should be `Carbon::now()` in the line `Carbon::parse(Carbon::now()->addDay());` or is that just a bad rewrite of the real code

Comment: @RiggsFolly `now()` is a short form of `Carbon::now()`. I think it was added in Laravel 8 *Edit* Nope, first shows up in the [5.5 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-now)

Comment: Ah @aynber Thanks, was looking at this from perspective of a non Laravel situation with just Carbon available to vanilla PHP

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell Eloquent that the field is a date field, with the `dates` value. This will convert any field specified to a Carbon object. Add this line to the top of your model class.

```
protected $dates = ['start_at'];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

Or

```
protected $casts = [
    'start_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s',
];
```

Comment: will this remove the time? and can we still perform `lte()` function? thanks for reply

Comment: and also sir. why `created_at` and `updated_at` fields remain timestamps without casting?

Comment: No, it should not remove the time. `created_at` and `updated_at` are cast to Carbon automatically. `By default, Eloquent will cast the created_at and updated_at columns to instances of Carbon, which extends the PHP DateTime class and provides an assortment of helpful methods. You may cast additional date attributes by defining additional date casts within your model's $casts property array. Typically, dates should be cast using the datetime or immutable_datetime cast types.`

Comment: after these, I will need to cast it again to Carbon timestamp, so I can perform `lte()`. am I right sir?

Comment: upvoted. thanks sir.

Comment: This will automatically cast any specified fields to Carbon, so you can use `lte`. (By the way, not everyone on the internet is a "sir")